# Microsoft Outlook - Saving of sent meeting/calendar requests

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, sent-items

Is there a way to save a sent meeting request in a specific folder (by default sent meeting requests go to the sent items folder)?  "Options/Save Sent Items To" is only available when sending emails and not meeting/calendar requests.

Answer (score 1):

Create a rule that applies for messages that are sent, of form type "Meeting Request" or "Meeting Cancellation". The action is to make a copy to the desired folder.

Comment: That won't work as I need to save them in different folders each time. I have a folder for all the different projects I'm managing and want to select the folder I want the meeting request saved in when creating the meeting request.

Comment: The question didn't mention that. Can't you just move the request from Sent Mail to the desired folder? Another option is to have a category or keyword for each project and have a different rule for each to save into a different folder.

Comment: I do currently move emails from Sent folder to desired folder but I'm always managing around 12 projects and I've got used to going into Options / Save Sent Items To for all mail items and would like to do the same for all the meeting requests I send. I thought maybe there was a way to add the Save Sent Items To function to the toolbar in a calendar request.  The rules are OK as I use different project numbers but the projects are always changing as some close and I'm allocated new ones. Thanks for your suggestions. :)

Comment: Rules can have lots of conditions, like "sent mail AND to <team X> AND form type is 'meeting request' OR 'meeting cancellation' -> move to <team X> folder". You'll need to create at least one rule per project, though, more if you need a precision filter that the rules can't handle all aspects of. **ALTERNATIVELY**, you could do this with a pretty simple Outlook add-in (which could have much more advanced logic than the rules engine supports, like identifying the project name based on the meeting invite and routing accordingly), but you'd need to know some software development to create that.